# MySQL order z1 then aa1

Tags: mysql

I have a field where it stores listing numbers for properties 04202011a1 to 04202011z1 then it goes to 04202011aa1 to 04202011zz1 and so on, how can i get the next number or letter combination since 04202011 its the date added and the last 1 its the userID the only part that increases are the letters

i can separate the id in pieces but not sure how to get the last one

thanks

CG

Comment: what is your next sequence?? `04202011aaa1` to `04202011zzz1` or `04202011b1` to `04202011z1`  please clarify your question

Comment: Why not just store those as separate fields?

Comment: the sequence is using first one letter (a to z) then it increases into 2 letters (aa to zz) then 3, 4 5 and so on, it increases depending on number of submissions by day

Comment: i am thinking on separte fields Mikko

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After you manage to pull out the non-numeric part (or simply store it in a seperate field as Mikko Wilkman has suggested), and you want `z` to appear before `aa`, you can use:

```
SELECT non_numeric_id FROM table 
ORDER BY length(non_numeric_id), non_numeric_id
```

**EDIT**

OK, to pull out the non-numeric id, assuming the column name is `id`, you can use this rather ugly solution:

```
SELECT
      id,
      REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(
      id,
      '1',''),'2',''),'3',''),'4',''),'5',''),'6',''),'7',''),'8',''),'9',''),'0','')
      AS clean_id
FROM table
ORDER BY length(clean_id), clean_id
```

The idea is to first remove all numbers, then order by length, then order alphabetically.

Comment: if i have 04202011a1 to 04202011z1 then 04202011aa1 to 04202011zz1 i want to order form mysql one letters first then the ones with 2 letters then 3 and so on